# I shredded a file from a 2TB external HDD, and the harddisk no longer works, What can i do?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

After shredding the file, the harddisk although gets detected, it doesnt read properly, neither it opens ups, How can i fix it or format it.
I tried `chkdsk`, but it fails after few steps.

Comment: Look at the SMART values to see if the harddisk is dead (and "shredding" just triggered it through the many writes). There's plenty of Q&A on how to interpret SMART values, search.

Comment: Disk is not showing in disk management service / disk manger apps etc, how will i check SMART values. If i open windows explorer, it shows green loading bar, that it, nothing happens!

Comment: The disk or the enclosure that holds it is faulty; or maybe just the power supply (if present); or the USB port (if applicable). Use another port. Test the disk by connecting directly (if possible) or with another enclosure. Test the enclosure with another compatible disk. This way you will learn where the problem is.

Comment: Remove it from any enclosures and tie it into your system directly. Still no response = dead disk. Also, Have you tried Diskpart? and you can still get LLF tools from the HDD GURU,